# SSH port forwarding: "Privileged ports can only be forwarded by root" error

Tags: ssh, sudo, openssh, port-forwarding

I wanted to forward my local 8080 port to the 80 port of the server I want to log in via SSH, so I did:

```
ssh -L 80:127.0.0.1:8080 -N -f myserver
```

But I get the error:

```
Privileged ports can only be forwarded by root.
```

I can execute sudo commands when logged in that server, but how can I do it for the purposes of port forwarding? (Note: appending `sudo` at the beginning of this command doesn't help, because the port `80` is not the port I want to use in localhost, but the port I want to target.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably want

```
ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:80 -N -f myserver
```

Local port comes first.  (That's not my political stance!)